# how do i set the size and the value of an input tag using knockout?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

When using knockoutjs, I want to set both the size and the value of the input field in a form.

For example,

```
var ViewModel = {
    size : ko.observable( n),   //coming from some calculation
    value : ko.observable()
}

'<input data-bind="value: value, size: size" />'
```

Using the above, I get the data set into the input area, but the size is the usual html default.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input data-bind="value: value,style: { width: UrWidth }" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<input data-bind="value: value, attr: { size: size }" />`

Also, works for type and some other attributes ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var viewModel = {
    someValue: ko.observable("edit me")
};</script>
```